# How to determine when state has finished updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, so bear with me. I'm working on a login form, this form will validate in real time AFTER the form was submitted and errors become true. Anyways, by default I have a property on state `isFormValid: false`.

This will update via a handleFormSubmission constructor:

```
  /**
   * handleFormSubmission, submission method for user
   * account login. Dispatches the login action.
   *
   * @param  {Object} event
   */
  handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    },() => {
      this.validateForm();
      if (this.state.isFormValid) {
        if (this.state.userCreatingAccount) {
          this.props.createUserAccount(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password,
            this.state.firstName,
            this.state.lastName
          )
        } else {
          this.props.login(
            this.state.email,
            this.state.password
          );
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I set `formSubmitted: true` in my state object, then execute form submission via a callback. My issue here is `this.validateForm()`. I need the code after it to be executed once `setState` inside of `this.validateForm()` has finished. Maybe I can promisify it? `this.validateForm().then(functio.......)`. Having a problem doing that since this function doesn't just update state once, does it multiple times dynamically.

This is my validate form function:

```
  /**
   * function validateForm, error handling for
   * dynamic form input fields. Resets state errors
   * on exection, then updates state via callback.
   */
  validateForm(){
    // Reset state.
    this.setState({
      isFormValid: true,
      errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {
        email: {},
        password: {},
        firstName: {},
        lastName: {}
      })
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.formSubmitted) {
        // Iterate over input fields, if length is 0
        // set an error via the state name.
        for (var inputField in this.state.errors) {
          if (this.state.errors.hasOwnProperty(inputField)) {
            if (inputField !== 'email') {
              if (
                !this.state.userCreatingAccount && 
                inputField !== 'firstName' && 
                inputField !== 'lastName'
              ) {
                if (this.state[inputField].length === 0) {
                  this.setState({
                    isFormValid: false,
                    errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {
                      [inputField]: {
                        required: true
                      }
                    })
                  });
                }
              } else {
                if (this.state[inputField].length === 0) {
                  this.setState({
                    isFormValid: false,
                    errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {
                      [inputField]: {
                        required: true
                      }
                    })
                  });
                }
              }
            } else {
              // Email validation.
              if (this.state[inputField].length === 0) {
                this.setState({
                  isFormValid: false,
                  errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {
                    [inputField]: {
                      required: true
                    }
                  })
                });
              } else if (!/^((?!.*\.\.)[a-z0-9\.\-]+[^\.]@[a-z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+)$/mgi.test(
                this.state[inputField]
              )) {
                this.setState({
                  isFormValid: false,
                  errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {
                    [inputField]: {
                      invalid: true
                    }
                  })
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Long story short, this function updates state for input fields. It does it dynamically, meaning for 1,2,3,4, etc. fields, depending on those field values. I want the logic inside of this.validateForm() to finish first. The code right after it depends on the new state values that are set inside of this.validateForm(). However setState is asynchronous.

Hope this question makes sense! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the logic after `this.validateForm()` in the first snippet to execute after the function itself is finished?

Comment: I want the logic inside of `this.validateForm()` to finish first. The code right after it depends on the new state values that are set inside of `this.validateForm()`. However `setState` is asynchronous. @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use React component lifecycle. I love this article about the explanation: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/, or you can read about setState from here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate.
We can use `componentDidUpdate()` to perform action after component's state change. Here's the modification of your code:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.state.isFormValid) {
   if (this.state.userCreatingAccount) {
    this.props.createUserAccount(
       this.state.email,
       this.state.password,
       this.state.firstName,
       this.state.lastName
     )
   } else {
     this.props.login(
       this.state.email,
       this.state.password
     );
   }
}

handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true
    },() => {
      this.validateForm();
      /* move them to componentDidUpdate() */
      //if (this.state.isFormValid) {
      //  if (this.state.userCreatingAccount) {
      //   this.props.createUserAccount(
      //      this.state.email,
      //      this.state.password,
      //      this.state.firstName,
      //      this.state.lastName
      //    )
      //  } else {
      //    this.props.login(
      //      this.state.email,
      //      this.state.password
      //    );
      //  }
      }
    });
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: This will trigger the `createUserAccount()` or `login()` functions any time the React state is updated. I imagine that's not what OP wants.

Comment: @Chris but it always check whether `isFormValid` is true or not, so if `isFormValid` remains false both methods will not be triggered

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a bit too complex for me to provide a working example, but I think I can give you a hint of what you could do.

The first issue I see is that you have way, way too many `setState()`. This isn't bad per se, but managing complex logic is a headache. It also becomes suddenly easy to accidentally have cases where you get multiple re-renders, all in vain.

Here's what I would do:

1. Break out any state variables that aren't directly tied with the presentation of your UI. For example, *it seems* like your `formSubmitted` variable is only used in your logic to determine an `if...else` outcome.
   You might have to double-check this, but if that's the case, put such variables in your component instance instead. Like `this.formSubmitted` instead of `this.state.formSubmitted`. Why do this?  It simplifies your application logic and saves you from doing an async `setState` and then continue your logic in the callback...
2. Don't make any state changes in `validateForm()`. Instead, construct a *new object* that mirrors that of the state you want in the next render. At the end of the function, return this constructed object.
3. You can now in your `handleFormSubmission()` function set the state with `this.setState(obj)` where `obj` is the object you returned from step 2 above. In the callback of the `setState()` do the last bit of logic. If your returned object contains all variables needed (I didn't check) you could even skip the callback and just check against `obj` instead of `this.state`.

---

**TL;DR** Strive towards always doing a **single `setState()`** in any one action or process in your application. This isn't always possible, but should be in 99.999% of times.

Good luck.